# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sbt.package$.Zero()Lsbt/Global$;

Tags: sbt, scala.js

When using Scala.js 0.6.20 (`addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.20")` in `project/plugins.sbt`), the following error happens when trying to sbt import the project using sbt 0.13.15:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sbt.package$.Zero()Lsbt/Global$;
        at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$.org$scalajs$sbtplugin$ScalaJSPluginInternal$$scalaJSStageSettings(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:254)
        at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$22.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:446)
        at org.scalajs.sbtplugin.ScalaJSPluginInternal$$anonfun$22.apply(ScalaJSPluginInternal.scala:446)
        at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:54)
        at scala.Function2$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function2.scala:53)
```

Similar problem: https://gitter.im/scala-js/scala-js?at=59b53890b59d55b823db1dcd

Answer (score 19):

As the [release notes mention](http://www.scala-js.org/news/2017/09/01/announcing-scalajs-0.6.20/), Scala.js 0.6.20 requires sbt 0.13.16 or above. To achieve this, the `project/build.properties` file should be modified to set:

```
sbt.version=0.13.16
```

(or something compatible)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: downgrade scala.js to `0.6.19` (say, for Coursera course capstone)

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.19") >> project/plugins.sbt
```